# What sort of indexing method can I use to store the distances between X^2 vectors in an array without redundancy?

Tags: c, vector, indexing, distance, redundancy

I'm working on a demo that requires a lot of vector math, and in profiling, I've found that it spends the most time finding the distances between given vectors.

Right now, it loops through an array of X^2 vectors, and finds the distance between each one, meaning it runs the distance function X^4 times, even though (I think) there are only (X^2)/2 unique distances.

It works something like this: (pseudo c)

```
#define MATRIX_WIDTH 8

typedef float vec2_t[2];
vec2_t matrix[MATRIX_WIDTH * MATRIX_WIDTH];

...

for(int i = 0; i < MATRIX_WIDTH; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < MATRIX_WIDTH; j++)
    {
        float xd, yd;
        float distance;

        for(int k = 0; k < MATRIX_WIDTH; k++)
        {
            for(int l = 0; l < MATRIX_WIDTH; l++)
            {
                int index_a = (i * MATRIX_LENGTH) + j;
                int index_b = (k * MATRIX_LENGTH) + l;

                xd = matrix[index_a][0] - matrix[index_b][0];
                yd = matrix[index_a][1] - matrix[index_b][1];

                distance = sqrtf(powf(xd, 2) + powf(yd, 2));
            }
        }

        // More code that uses the distances between each vector
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is create and populate an array of (X^2) / 2 distances without redundancy, then reference that array when I finally need it. However, I'm drawing a blank on how to index this array in a way that would work. A hash table would do it, but I think it's much too complicated and slow for a problem that seems like it could be solved by a clever indexing method.

EDIT: This is for a flocking simulation.

Comment: Why are there only X^2/2 unique distances?  Do you mean X^4/2?

Comment: Tell us why you need to calculate the distances in the first place.  It's possible you can reduce that need by creating a spatial index for your vectors.

Comment: And your calculated distances seem to be utterly lost except the last one, from the last loop iterations of the two inner-most loops. Please post **real code** and specify *why* you're calculating these point distances in the first place, which will likely go a long way in optimizing your loops.

Comment: How do you store your (mathematical) vectors? Do you have an array of these vectors? If so, a triangular matrix should do the trick for storing the distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

performance ideas:
a) if possible work with the squared distance, to avoid root calculation
b) never use pow for constant, integer powers - instead use xd*xd

I would consider changing your algorithm - O(n^4) is really bad. When dealing with interactions in physics (also O(n^4) for distances in 2d field) one would implement b-trees etc and neglect particle interactions with a low impact. But it will depend on what "more code that uses the distance..." really does.

just did some considerations: the number of unique distances is 0.5*n*n(+1) with n = w*h.
If you write down when unique distances occur, you will see that both inner loops can be reduced, by starting at i and j.

Additionally if you only need to access those distances via the matrix index, you can set up a 4D-distance matrix.

If memory is limited we can save up nearly 50%, as mentioned above, with a lookup function that will access a triangluar matrix, as Code-Guru said. We would probably precalculate the line index to avoid summing up on access

```
float distanceArray[(H*W+1)*H*W/2];
int lineIndices[H];

searchDistance(int i, int j)
{
    return i<j?distanceArray[i+lineIndices[j]]:distanceArray[j+lineIndices[i]];
}
```

Comment: I already use the squared distance, I simply added the sqrt to make it clear what the code was doing. I also don't use pow() or powf() in my code for squaring. Again, that was to make the intention of the code clear. I've also edited my original post to clarify that this is for a flocking simulation.